# How to load Items in combo box on Formload from a class file

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-2.0

I would like to load the items that were declared in class file when the Form loads can any one give me an idea

My class file code is as follows

```
namespace ACHDAL
{
   public class TansactionCode
   {
    string[] strTransactionCodes ={"20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34",
        "35","36","37","38","39","41","42","43","44","46","47","48","49","51","52","53","54","55","56","80",
        "81","82","83","84","85","86"};

}
}
```

Would like to load all these in to the combo box when the Form loads if any thing has to be done in this code please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You populate combo boxes by setting their [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx) property [(see here for more details on what you can bind to them)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8ybe6s2%28VS.80%29.aspx).

To do this you'll need to expose the list first, so put it into a property. This is how the form will access it, after creating a new instance of the class.

```
public string[] TransactionCodes
{
    get { return strTransactionCodes; }
    set { strTransactionCodes = value; }
}
```

Then do this on the FormLoad event

eg

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TansactionCode trans = new TansactionCode();    // Create new instance
    combobox.DataSource = trans.TransactionCodes;   // Access the list property
}
```

Comment: How can i get that string name in the form

Comment: Yeah you can do that but its bad practise, you should generally encapsulate class fields in a property. See Jon Skeets blog post here for reasons why: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx